# Seasonal adjustment in Python and Scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am looking to seasonally adjust monthly data, using Python. As you can see from these series: [www.emconfidential.com](http://www.emconfidential.com/),  there is a high seasonal component to the data. I would like to adjust for this so that I can better guage if the series trend is rising or falling. Anybody know how to do this easily using scipy or other Python library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no magical python library that will do seasonal adjustments for you. Applications that do this kind of thing tend to be [rather large](http://www.census.gov/srd/www/x12a/).

You'll need to work out the maths [yourself](http://www.dst.dk/upload/seasonal.pdf) and then use scipy to calculate the rest for you.

Comment: Thanks I think you're right that I'll just program it myself. Your PDF is a good source. However not quite true that there are no python libraries that do this: http://hydroclimpy.sourceforge.net/generated/scikits.hydroclimpy.core.ts_addons.deseasonalize.html#scikits.hydroclimpy.core.ts_addons.deseasonalize

Problem is above is not the algorithm I want. I am looking for an X12 Arima implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the pdf link seems to be broken, or the file has been removed. How to get a copy of it anyway?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20061017234327/http://www.dst.dk/upload/seasonal.pdf

Answer (score 19):

Statsmodels can do this.  They have a basic seasonal decomposition and also a wrapper to Census X13 adjustment.  You could also use rpy2 to access some of R's excellent SA libraries.  Here is statsmodels seasonal decomp:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.options.display.mpl_style = 'default'
%matplotlib inline

dta = sm.datasets.co2.load_pandas().data.resample("M").fillna(method="ffill")

res = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(dta)

fig = res.plot()
fig.set_size_inches(10, 5)
plt.tight_layout()
```

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/release/version0.6.html

Comment: The statsmodels library now includes the STL (Seasonal and Trend decomposition using Loess) decomposition. See documentation for [statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html) and [the example](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/stl_decomposition.html). The documentation for seasonal_decompose now Notes that "This is a naive decomposition. More sophisticated methods should be preferred", and STL appears to currently be the only such method included in statsmodels.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a package that seems to be exactly what you are looking for! Check out the `seasonal` package, here is the [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/seasonal/0.3.1). I personally found it to be very useful, wondering what others think.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html#python-api) developed by the data science team at Facebook. It has Python+R API and is used for time-series prediction although you can use it just for decomposing your series into its components (trend vs seasonality). You can easily adjust and visualize the decomposition:

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create series
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.arange(0, 10, .285)
y_periodic = np.sin(x*np.pi)
y_random = np.random.normal(size=len(x))
y_trend = x / 10.
df = pd.DataFrame({'ds': pd.date_range('01-01-2017', periods=len(x)),
                    'y': y_periodic})
df.head() # has to be a DataFrame with columns "ds" and "y"
df.set_index('ds').plot(style='-*')
```

[image: Series with noise]

```
# Estimate the model
m = Prophet()
m.fit(df);
forecast = m.predict(df)
m.plot_components(forecast);
```

[image: Trend and seasonality decomposition]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the programming aspect of this but I would seriously consider moving averages to solve this.

Comment: That works for a 12 period moving average, the only problem is that what if I want to extrapolate from the last 3 or 6 months of data, to start getting an idea of the developing trend? Then I need a proper seasonal adjustment.